# R Shiny renderMenu unexpected behavior

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm coming back to R after a more than two years break, and it's not easy.

I've created an interface thanks to shinydashboard package, including two different menus in the sidebar: one short and one extended. The extended menu should display when you click on the "Country" tab, but it opens very fast and then returns to short menu, and I don't understand why. The menus are rendered from the server side. Thank you very much for any help.

This is the ui code :

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(shiny)
 library(shinydashboard)

 ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(
       title = "2019 CENSUS",
       titleWidth = 500), # f. de dashboardHeader

     dashboardSidebar(#Sidebar contents
       sidebarMenu(id = "Menu1",
                   sidebarMenuOutput("Menu"))

     ), # closes dashboardSidebar

     #### BODY CONTENTS #####

     dashboardBody(

       # Title
       tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                                 .main-header .logo {
                                 font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
                                 font-weight: bold;
                                 font-size: 16px;
                                 }
                                 '))), # closes tags$head(tags$style(HTML('

       tabItems(
         # Geo levels tab contents
         tabItem(tabName = "levels",
                 fluidRow(                
                   box(width = 12, background = "light-blue",title = "Welcome", "Please choose a geo level from the three available then click on the 'Home datas' tab") # closes box
                 ) # closes fluidRow
         ), # closes tabItem

         # Country level tab contents
         tabItem(tabName = "country",
                 fluidRow(
                   box(title = "Country level : please, click on the 'Home datas' tab to view datas", width = 12, background = "olive") # closes box
                ) # closes fluidRow
         ), # closes tabItem

         # Counties tab contents
         tabItem(tabName = "counties",
                 fluidRow(
                   box(title = "Counties level", width = 3, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
                       checkboxGroupInput("dynamic_provinces", label = "", c("North","South","Islands"))) # closes box
                 ), # closes fluidRow

                 fluidRow(
                   box(title = "North county", width = 9, background = "light-blue"),  # closes box

                   br()

                 ), # closes fluidRow

                 fluidRow(
                  box(title = "South county", width = 9, background = "orange"), # closes box

                   br()

                 ), # closes fluidRow

                 fluidRow(
                   box(title = "Islands county", width = 9, background = "olive"),  # closes box

                 ) # closes fluidRow

              ) # closes tabItem

            ) # closes tabItems

          ) # closes dashboardBody    

        ) # closes dashboardPage
```

And the server code :

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

   # Initialize reactive values
   rv10 <- reactiveValues(selection = numeric())

   rv10$selection <- 0 # extended/short menu reactive value : extended menu if = 1/ short menu if = 0

   #### FOCUS ON THE WELCOME TAB ####

   updateTabItems(session, "Menu1", "welcome")

   ############## SETTING MENU DEPENDING ON THE VALUE OF rv10$selection ################

   output$Menu <- renderMenu({
     if (rv10$selection == 1) { # extended/short menu reactive value : extended menu if = 1/ short menu if = 0
       sidebarMenu(# Short menu
         menuItem(strong("Geo levels"), tabName = "levels", icon = icon("arrow-down"),selected = TRUE),
         menuSubItem("Country", tabName = "country", icon = icon("globe-americas")),
         menuSubItem("Counties", tabName = "counties", icon = icon("parking")),
         menuItem(strong("Home datas"), tabName = "home_datas", icon = icon("home"),
                  menuSubItem("Home data 1", tabName = "home_1", icon = icon("home")),
                  menuSubItem("Home data 2", tabName = "home_2", icon = icon("home"))),
         menuItem(strong("Quit"), tabName = "quit", icon = icon("remove"))

       ) # closes sidebarMenu
     } # closes if

     else {

       sidebarMenu(# Extended menu
         menuItem(strong("Geo levels"), tabName = "levels", icon = icon("arrow-down"),selected = TRUE),
         menuSubItem("Country", tabName = "country", icon = icon("globe-americas")),
         menuSubItem("Counties", tabName = "counties", icon = icon("parking")),
         menuItem(strong("Quit"), tabName = "quit", icon = icon("remove"))

       ) # closes sidebarMenu

     } # closes else

   }) # closes output$Menu <- renderMenu({

   #### OBSERVEEVENT #####

   observeEvent(input$Menu1, {

     # If click on the "Geo levels" tab -> short menu

     if (input$Menu1 == "levels"){

       rv10$selection <- 0 # rv10$selection = 0 -> displaying the short menu
       print(paste("rv10$selection value =", rv10$selection)) # displaying the value of rv10$selection
     }

     # If click on the "Country" tab -> extended menu

     if(input$Menu1 == "country"){

       rv10$selection <- 1 # rv10$selection = 1 -> displaying the extended menu
       print(paste("rv10$selection value =", rv10$selection))
     }

     # If click on the "counties" tab -> short menu

     if(input$Menu1 == "counties"){

       rv10$selection <- 0 # rv10$selection = 0 -> displaying the short menu
       print(paste("rv10$selection value =", rv10$selection))
     }

     #### CLOSING THE APP ####

     if (input$Menu1 == "quit"){

       print("Quit")
       stopApp()}

   }) # closes ObserveEvent(input$Menu1

 }) # closes shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with your closing brackets. `menuSubItem()` is placed inside a `menuItem()`.

Incorrect:

```r
 sidebarMenu(# Short menu
         menuItem(strong("Geo levels"), tabName = "levels", icon = icon("arrow-down"),selected = TRUE),
         menuSubItem("Country", tabName = "country", icon = icon("globe-americas")),
         menuSubItem("Counties", tabName = "counties", icon = icon("parking")),
         menuItem(strong("Home datas"), tabName = "home_datas", icon = icon("home"),
                  menuSubItem("Home data 1", tabName = "home_1", icon = icon("home")),
                  menuSubItem("Home data 2", tabName = "home_2", icon = icon("home"))),
         menuItem(strong("Quit"), tabName = "quit", icon = icon("remove"))

       ) # closes sidebarMenu
```

Correct version:

```r
sidebarMenu(# Short menu
        menuItem(strong("Geo levels"), tabName = "levels", icon = icon("arrow-down"),selected = TRUE,
        menuSubItem("Country", tabName = "country", icon = icon("globe-americas")),
        menuSubItem("Counties", tabName = "counties", icon = icon("parking"))),
        menuItem(strong("Home datas"), tabName = "home_datas", icon = icon("home"),
                 menuSubItem("Home data 1", tabName = "home_1", icon = icon("home")),
                 menuSubItem("Home data 2", tabName = "home_2", icon = icon("home"))),
        menuItem(strong("Quit"), tabName = "quit", icon = icon("remove"))
```

All I've done is remove the closing bracket at the end of the first `menuItem()` and placed it at the end of the second `menuSubItem()`

[image]

Full server code:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Initialize reactive values
  rv10 <- reactiveValues(selection = numeric())

  rv10$selection <- 0 # extended/short menu reactive value : extended menu if = 1/ short menu if = 0

  #### FOCUS ON THE WELCOME TAB ####

  updateTabItems(session, "Menu1", "welcome")

  ############## SETTING MENU DEPENDING ON THE VALUE OF rv10$selection ################

  output$Menu <- renderMenu({
    if (rv10$selection == 1) { # extended/short menu reactive value : extended menu if = 1/ short menu if = 0
      sidebarMenu(# Short menu
        menuItem(strong("Geo levels"), tabName = "levels", icon = icon("arrow-down"),selected = TRUE,
        menuSubItem("Country", tabName = "country", icon = icon("globe-americas")),
        menuSubItem("Counties", tabName = "counties", icon = icon("parking")),
        startExpanded = TRUE
        ),
        menuItem(strong("Home datas"), tabName = "home_datas", icon = icon("home"),
                 menuSubItem("Home data 1", tabName = "home_1", icon = icon("home")),
                 menuSubItem("Home data 2", tabName = "home_2", icon = icon("home")), 
                 startExpanded = TRUE
                 ),
        menuItem(strong("Quit"), tabName = "quit", icon = icon("remove"))

      ) # closes sidebarMenu
    } # closes if

    else {

      sidebarMenu(# Extended menu
        menuItem(strong("Geo levels"), tabName = "levels", icon = icon("arrow-down"),selected = TRUE),
        menuSubItem("Country", tabName = "country", icon = icon("globe-americas")),
        menuSubItem("Counties", tabName = "counties", icon = icon("parking")),
        menuItem(strong("Quit"), tabName = "quit", icon = icon("remove"))

      ) # closes sidebarMenu

    } # closes else

  }) # closes output$Menu <- renderMenu({

  #### OBSERVEEVENT #####

  observeEvent(input$Menu1, {

    # If click on the "Geo levels" tab -> short menu

    if (input$Menu1 == "levels"){

      rv10$selection <- 0 # rv10$selection = 0 -> displaying the short menu
      print(paste("rv10$selection value =", rv10$selection)) # displaying the value of rv10$selection
    }

    # If click on the "Country" tab -> extended menu

    if(input$Menu1 == "country"){

      rv10$selection <- 1 # rv10$selection = 1 -> displaying the extended menu
      print(paste("rv10$selection value =", rv10$selection))
    }

    # If click on the "counties" tab -> short menu

    if(input$Menu1 == "counties"){

      rv10$selection <- 0 # rv10$selection = 0 -> displaying the short menu
      print(paste("rv10$selection value =", rv10$selection))
    }

    #### CLOSING THE APP ####

    if (input$Menu1 == "quit"){

      print("Quit")
      stopApp()}

  }) # closes ObserveEvent(input$Menu1

} # closes shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
```

Then run with:

```r
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Mr.Rlover, thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, it's not what I wish, excuse me, I was not clear. With your solution, the "Home datas" tab is open at the begining of the program. At the start of the program, I would like to see the "Country" tab and the "Counties" tab only. And only when we click on the "Country" tab, the "Home datas" tab appears under the "Counties" tab. When we look at the console, we can see that the rv10$selection value should be 1, but in the console its value is 1 and then 0, so the extended menu does not appear. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's what happens when I remove the bracket. Did you make the amendments? I have now placed the full server code, replace your sever code with mine and it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Rlover, now it's nearly perfect. Just one last question please : is it possible to keep the "Country" and "Counties" tabs visible when I click on the "Country" tab ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, set ````startExpanded = TRUE```` in the ````menuItems()```` that have ````menuSubItem()````. Server code is updated with these changes.

Comment: Oh yes, so great ! I didn't know the startExpanded command. Thanks to you, I will be able continue working. Many thanks Mr.Rlover